# Why is this reactjs useEffect function running endlessly?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

Here is a useEffect hook that I used in reactjs:

Problem: The useEffect calls `fetchAllCategories()` endlessly. Infact, over 1000 requests until I terminate. I only want it to run on page mount and when I click on the button to change catName state. What could I be doing wrong?

```
  const [catName, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const categoryRef = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
   
         const fetchAllCategories = async () =>{
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/category`)
        return setCategories(res.data);
       
        
        }catch(err){

        }

        
    }

    fetchAllCategories()
    
   
}, [catName])


 //create new category

const createNewCategory = async ()=>{
    const categoryName = {
        catName: categoryRef.current.value
    }
    try{
        const response = await axiosPrivate.post(`${BASE_URL}/category`, categoryName, { withCredentials: true,
        headers:{authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`}
        })
        return setCategories([response.data])
        
    }catch(err){

    }
    
  }
```

The button that triggers changes in catName

```
<button onClick={ createNewCategory} className='button-general'>Create</button>
```

Comment: The `dependency-array` says: `[catName]` which means that the code will be invoked/executed when `catName` changes. Then, within the `useEffect` the code uses `setCategories` which effectively changes `catName`. Since `catName` changed, the `useEffect` executes & again changes `catName` (using `setCategories`). Now, since `catName` changed, the `useEffect` executes again... so on, and on, and on. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know the problem. Let me see how to fix it

Comment: Nikolay's answer covers it, I think. Try it out - it should work. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You trigger the effect to be run on change of `catNames`, and then change `catNames` from the effect itself. This results in the endless self-triggering of the effect.

One solution could be to make your effect depend on nothing:

```
useEffect(() => {
....
}, []);
```

Comment: Well, if I make the useEffect to depend on nothing, I need to refresh the page to trigger it when the catName changes.

Comment: `useState` takes care of that. You don't need to do it manually. Meaning, probably you don't eed the efffect at all, just a function that does `setCategories()`

Comment: Yea, this sounds like something that would work too. But I simply used another state and made the useEFfect to depend on that state. It is working now without endless calls. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for pointing out the issue to me. Since I now know the issue, I have been able to fix it. All I did was create another state and made the useEffect to depend on it. Then, whenever the button is clicked, I change the state to the opposite of the initial state. This works and doesnt cause endless calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need `catName` as a dependency, this can work for you:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllCategories = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/category`);
            return setCategories(res.data);
        } catch (err) {}
    };

    fetchAllCategories();
}, [JSON.stringify(catName)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you update the catName state inside the useEffect using `setCategories(res.data)` this keeps triggering your useEffect thus an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You programmed it to run endlessly.

#### **REASON**

See, this React hook `useEffect` has two parameters:

1. **Effect**, the callback function which is called whenever the component renders.
2. **List of Dependencies** on which the `useEffect` hook depends and re-renders if any such dependency is updated.

Now, in your case, you've passed `catName` as a dependency, whose state is updated when the button is clicked. This causes `useEffect` to call the callback function which calls `fetchAllCategories()` which also update `catName`. And this causes an endless loop.

#### SOLUTION

Just remove the dependency from useEffect as:

```
useEffect(() {
    ...
}, []);
```

Now, updating `catName` won't cause the `effect` (The Callback function) to be called endlessly.